# Spring Security : how to have differents authorities/ privilegies for two differents user in the same role?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Scenario.
Spring MVC + Spring Security 4.
Different Role (ex: Admin, DBA Admin, Simple User).
4 user (Admin Adam, DBA Admin Sam, Simple User Tom and Simple user Luke).

I have due simple users (Tom and Luke) but I would like to have for each users different authority.
Example: Tom grant for CRUD data and Luke only for readData.
Any suggestion please?

Thanks

Comment: I think ACL is what you are looking for. Spring Security has an ACL modul.

Comment: i found a solution to your problem on this article : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-acl you ca check it i am sure it will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks. 
How can i interact from my view (jsp) to ACL with some Spring tld?